# how to loop over a property of type array of object

Tags: rythm

I'm a total rythm newbie and got stuck on one of my simple tests (tested here: http://fiddle.rythmengine.com/)

I guess it's easiest to explain the problem in a simple example:

My JSON input args:

```
{myObj: 
 {name: "test", values: [ {id: 1}, {id: 2} ]
 }
}
```

so the values property is an array of object - and those objects only have one property `id`.

my test-template:

```
@args Object myObj
Hello @myObj.name@

@for (Object v: myObj.values) {
  @// this fails
}
```

this fails:

```
org.rythmengine.exception.CompileException: values cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

what is wrong here?

i.e. outside of the loop I can access myObj.values

```
@args Object myObj
Hello @myObj.name@

@myObj.values@
```

Answer (score 2):

You declared `myObj` as `Object` which doesn't have the `value` property at all.

Solution:

Make your JSON string look like:

```
{ 
name: "test", values: [ {id: 1}, {id: 2} ]
}
```

Your template code:

```
@args String name, Map[] values

Hello @name@

@for (Map v: values) {
  @v.get("id")
}
```

Result:

```
Hello test
 1
 2
```

Tested on http://fiddle.rythmengine.com/

Comment: I cannot change the JSON - the true JSON is much more complicated and I get it from an external source. So the to rephrase the question: "how to iterate over the values in the given JSON data"? If possible at all...

Comment: It's better for you to define a class that mapped to the JSON structure you got, then declare your Rythm template argument using that java class